# MVC - Tweet from Controller not working well

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter

I have a problem with Twitter tweet from my application, I don't understand why not working.

This is my code:

```
TwitterHelper.Tweet(Message, Request,
     unitOfWork.UserProfileRepository.GetByID(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).ToString());
```

If I use my code from the Controller's `ActionResult Index...` method or from Edit method, working fine.

But If I use from my own

```
ActionResult SendTweet(string message) 
{
    ...
```

it is not working. No error message, just not reaching the twitter, don't want to authenticate, etc.

I call this method from my view with ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/MyController/SendTweet",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { Message: $('#Message').val()},
    success: function (data) { $('#Message').text = ''; }
});
```

If i debug my controller I have the Message value and going through the call and no exception, but not working.

**Update**
The Request parameter is used after the Twitter authentication. What is happening: If i call from Index for example:

```
if(userName != TwitterHelper._userName) 
{ 
    TwitterHelper._userName = userName; 
    TwitterHelper._accessToken = null;  
    TwitterHelper._accessTokenSecret = null; 
    TwitterHelper._userId = null; 
    TwitterHelper._screenName = null; 
}
```

after that:

```
SortedDictionary<string, string> requestTokenParams = 
    new SortedDictionary<string, string>(); 

requestTokenParams.Add("oauth_callback", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri); 

var tokenResponse = 
    TwitterHelper.GetToken("api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";, requestTokenParams); 

NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tokenResponse); 

var loginUrl = "api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token="; 
    + qscoll["oauth_token"];
```

and:

```
//(HERE THE BROWSER SHOWS THE TWITTER LOGIN) –
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(loginUrl);
```

If I call Tweet from the SendTweet method the way is the same. But here: `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(loginUrl);` not shows anything, no login page. nothing happenin

Could you please help ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it hit a breakpoint at the `SenTweet` action? If not, try to decorate it with the `[HttpPost]` attribute and correct the `Message: $('#Message').val()` to `message: $('#Message').val()` (or other way round in your action)

Comment: Yes, it hits a breakpoint and the parameter "Message" is not empty too, so that part is working I think.

Comment: No, I mean that is okay, I see the correct message text in my controller.

Comment: can you check the return value of: `unitOfWork.UserProfileRepository.GetByID(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).ToString()`

Comment: Checked, that value is okay too. Same value as when I do this from Index or Edit.

Comment: Hmm, so basically the only difference seems to be that you are using it in an `ajax` call. How is the `Request` parameter in the `TwitterHelper.Tweet(` function used?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `Redirect` from a `AJAX` call. (well... basically)

The line:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(loginUrl);
```

Is invalid because you are performing a asynchronous post.

Here is how it works:

With:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/MyController/SendTweet",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { Message: $('#Message').val()},
    success: function (data) { $('#Message').text = ''; }
});
```

your browser is requesting a asynchronous connection with your server and is will wait for data to arrive. If this data contains a `Redirect` this is not really a valid instruction in this context. It just waits for data, not for instructions.

**How to fix it:**

Make your `ActionResult SendTweet(string message)` suitable for `json`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendTweet(string message)
{
    bool isAuthenticationRequired = //detect wether a user needs to login

    if (isAuthenticationRequired)
    {
        //returns indicator that login is required
        return Json(new { result = "unauthenticated" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //do normal stuff

    return Json(new { result = "tweet send!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then, update your `ajax` call to handle the result:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/MyController/SendTweet",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { Message: $('#Message').val()},
    success: function (data) { 

        if (data.result == "unauthenticated"){
            location.href = "an action which will redirect to the login page";
            return;
        }            

        $('#Message').text = ''; }
});
```

Maybe the `location.href` needs some additional parameters to re-post the data, but for now this seems sufficient.

**update**

I am not really familiar with the `Twitter API` but to redirect to the correct page you'll need a normal `ActionResult`, probably the one with the `Ajax` call on it. You can add some parameters to the url, or maybe the `Twitter API` provide this kind of functionality.

To redirect back to the correct page, take a look at:

```
requestTokenParams.Add("oauth_callback", 
      HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

The

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

will send you to the `SendTweet` action again but since this is a `json` `post` action, it won't be able to find it.

You'll need to change

```
requestTokenParams.Add("oauth_callback", 
      HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

to the page with the `ajax` call or another page that does this and than redirect to your original page. You can also add some parameters to resend the tweet message. Something like this:

```
requestTokenParams.Add("oauth_callback", 
      "someactionresult?tweetmessage=" + message);
```

with action:

```
public ActionResult someactionresult (string tweetmessage)
{
    //do twitter stuff
    return RedirectToAction("your original url");
}
```

Comment: Minor detail: I am not sure if it's `if (data.result == "unauthenticated"){` or `if (data == "unauthenticated"){`

Comment: Almost done :) Thank you for the code, the first step is absolute better :)

Now I'm not authenticated, then I get the login page, but after the login the browser goes to 
http://localhost/MyController/SendTweet?oauth_token=...&oauth_verifier=...

and shows an 
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.
Error. 

how can I do after the authentication do Tweet automatically ?

Comment: Now similar issue. Now after authentication goes to Twitter.com and no tweet. with the

    requestTokenParams.Add("oauth_callback", 
      "MyController/DoTweet?tweetmessage=" + message);

not reach this method. Not hits the breakpoint what is in this DoTweet method

Comment: The callback url is invalid `requestTokenParams.Add("oauth_callback", "MyController/DoTweet?tweetmessage=" + message);` should be `requestTokenParams.Add("oauth_callback", "http://localhost or something/MyController/DoTweet?tweetmessage=" + message);`